# Include certificate for webservice

Tags: web-services, delphi, ssl

Is it possible to call webservice in Delphi with certificate loaded from SQL base?
I need to make a webservice which logins with certificate which is saved as image in SQL base, and would need to be loaded from it and then called with webservice desipe not being installed in Store on a device currently using it using class generated by WDSL.

Comment: I guess you're trying to access an https web service that requires client side certificates?

Comment: Yes and I need to somehow register the certificate with it